# How can I get an application correctly working on IIS 7.5?

Tags: php, laravel, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having a problem with an application that I am trying to setup using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

My application is PHP based and utilizing Laravel 5.2 framework. To get my environment setup, I did the following

1. Installed [PHP Manager](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/)
2. Installed [Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributiable (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
3. [I installed PHP 5.6.18](http://windows.php.net/download/)
4. I placed my Laravel Application into `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. My application root folder is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Laravel`
5. I gave the IIS_IUSERS a full control on the the `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folder like [Laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation) instructs.
6. I opened IIS 7.5. From the connection panel on the left hand side I clicked on "Application Pools" and added a new Application Pool Named "LaravelPoolApps" with the default identity i.e. [ApplicationPoolIdentity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).
7. Then in the "connections" panel I navigated to my `Laravel` folder found under the `Default Web Site` Node. I converted it to an Application "by right clicking on it and selecting "Convert to Application". For the pool I selected "LaravelPoolApps" to utilize my new AppPool.
8. Then, I click on my `Laravel` application node and selected "Basic Setting" in the "Action" Panel on the right hand side. Finally, I changed the physical Path to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Laravel\public` to direct the traffic to the public folder which is laravel application starter.

While on the "Basic Setting" page, I clicked the `test settings` button I get a warning like you see in the screenshot below
[image]

When I try to open my website `http://localhost/laravel` I get HTTP Error 500. However, if I click on `connect as` and connect as network administrator everything works with no problems and I am able to open`http://localhost/laravel` and it opens as it should.

**Question**

How can I get my application to work without having to connect as admin?